# How to create a link without showing the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

Could someone please share how to create a link and not letting the users know the url of the link?

For example in the following website, when you hover over the practice groups the mouse shows that its a hyperlink but the url doesn't get dsplayed.

verbling.com/community

I am developing a similar page. Kindly share how to create a link and not letting the users know the url of the link.

Comment: @No1_Melman I care because the links are created by google hangouts which does not have number of participant restriction. I do not want to show the link so that no one notes down the url and jumps into the link after the number of participants have reached the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this simple example with [jquery](http://jquery.com/)

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="do_action">Click Here</a>

$(function(){
    $('.do_action').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Open link on same page
        document.location.href = 'http://example.com';

       // Open link in tab or other window
       // window.open();
    });
});
```

For new tab [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)

Comment: Perfect. Now I can change the link dynamically based on my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can add a click function and set the location throgh javascript like:-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#target" ).click(function() {
      location.href = 'http://address.com';
    });
});
```

for this thing to work you have to include jquery, either from your server or from CDN like

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```